# Convert to ARC -- resolve forward references

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've inherited Objective-C code that I'm moving to ARC.  I've a number of .h files that declare a protocol and an interface that reference one another -- here's the basic pattern in the .h file

```
@class BasicService;
@class BasicServiceObserver;

@protocol BasicServiceObserver
-(void)UPnPEvent:(BasicService*)sender events:(NSDictionary*)events;
@end


@interface BasicService : NSObject <Events_Observer> {
    <<var declarations here>>
}

-(NSUInteger)addObserver:(BasicServiceObserver*)obs;
-(NSUInteger)removeObserver:(BasicServiceObserver*)obs;
-(BOOL)isObserver:(BasicServiceObserver*)obs;
@end
```

and in the .m file, the BasicServiceObserver ref is flagged as a forward reference.  The .m file includes the above .h file.

```
//Events_Observer
-(void)someEvent:(NSDictionary*)events{
    BasicServiceObserver *obs = nil;

    [mMutex lock];
    NSEnumerator *listeners = [mObservers objectEnumerator];
    while(obs = [listeners nextObject]){
        [obs someEvent:self events:events]; // <-- Receiver type 'BasicServiceObserver' for instance message is a forward declaration
    }
    [mMutex unlock];
}
```

Driving me nuts. I've tried to separate the the protocol into its own .h file and import it (and remove the @class declaration).  No joy there.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

thanks!

Comment: This isn't valid: `BasicServiceObserver *obs = nil;`. It should be; `id<BasicServiceObserver> obs = nil;`.

Comment: You don't have to set `@class BasicServiceObserver;`if you are declaring it bellow. Also, `BasicServiceObserver` isn't a class, so you cannot use `@class`

Comment: Also, just as a tip, in case you are just moving the files to ARC to be able to set your project as ARC. You can also selectively disable ARC for specific files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `BasicServiceObserver` is a protocol, not a class, it should not be forward-declared in this situation at all. Declaring it as a `@class` misleads the compiler into thinking that there would be an `@interface BasicServiceObserver` somewhere when there is no such interface.

Here is how you should get this to a state where it compiles:

```
@class BasicService;

@protocol BasicServiceObserver
-(void)UPnPEvent:(BasicService*)sender events:(NSDictionary*)events;
@end


@interface BasicService : NSObject <Events_Observer> {
    <<var declarations here>>
}

-(NSUInteger)addObserver:(id<BasicServiceObserver>)obs;
-(NSUInteger)removeObserver:(id<BasicServiceObserver>)obs;
-(BOOL)isObserver:(id<BasicServiceObserver>)obs;
@end
```

Similarly, in .m file

```
//Events_Observer
-(void)someEvent:(NSDictionary*)events{
    id<BasicServiceObserver> obs = nil;

    [mMutex lock];
    NSEnumerator *listeners = [mObservers objectEnumerator];
    while(obs = [listeners nextObject]){
        [obs someEvent:self events:events]; // <-- Receiver type 'BasicServiceObserver' for instance message is a forward declaration
    }
    [mMutex unlock];
}
```

Note: Since you are cleaning up the files anyway, consider moving the variables from the `<<var declarations here>>` section into a class extension in the .m file. This may help you reduce the number of headers included in the .h file, and to avoid propagating through your headers the unnecessary dependencies of the implementation

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, a class and a protocol are not the same thing.

Sometimes you do want to define both, e.g. the system UITableView class and the UITableViewDelegateProtocol protocol.

If you are going to have both a protocol and a class, I suggest adding the word protocol to the name of the protocol:

```
@protocol BasicServiceObserverProtocol
-(void)UPnPEvent:(BasicService*)sender events:(NSDictionary*)events;
@end
```

However, it's probably better to not create a BasicServiceObserver class. Instead, make all pointers to objects to conform to that protocol be

BasicServiceObserverProtocol, as @dasblinkenlight says in his post.